# Creating Java Web Service using Google AppEngine

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine, servlets, wsdl

I'm trying to create a simple web service application where I can retrieve a collection of strings and store them into a data store on the AppEngine server.

I have knowledge in Java and barely any knowledge of Java Servlets and its WAR standards.

I would like to at least have some direction on how to create a web service using the Java technology AppEngine provides. I've searched but the articles are sparse and too lengthy while not providing any simple solutions.

I'd love it if I can create a web service using Java's annotations just like you can do in .NET with attributes.

I'd appreciate links to articles and guidance a full source answer is not required but would be appreciated.

No python based answers please.

Comment: Does your web service need to comply to any particular standards (i.e., SOAP?) or are you OK with something more RESTful?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

IMO, there is no simple solution to build a Web Service on GAE with Java.

But, it's still achievable. Let's start with the [Web Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) we want to build.

> In common usage the term refers to
>   clients and servers that communicate
>   over the Hypertext Transfer Protocol
>   (HTTP) protocol used on the web. Such
>   services tend to fall into one of two
>   camps: **Big Web Services** and
>   **RESTful Web Services**.

"Big Web Services" use SOAP/RPC format and RESTful Web Services use REST style one. You can [read more about SOAP vs REST](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/431.cfm).

There are lots of [Java open source Web Services frameworks out there](http://wiki.apache.org/ws/StackComparison). Most of them are generally based on the Java API for XML Web Services (JAX-WS), part of the Java EE platform.
JAX-WS is **not supported** by Google App Engine as specified in the list [Will it play in App Engine](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine). So forget about the "cool Java's annotations".

But, **Restlet seems compatible with GAE**. So if you think REST could be an option for you, I would go ahead and take a look at the [Hello World tutorial of Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/firstSteps). Then, I'd go ahead and read the article on [how to integrate Restlet with GAE](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/275-restlet/252-restlet.html).

Comment: "JAX-WS is not supported by Google App Engine as specified in the list Will it play in App Engine. So forget about the "cool Java's annotations"."

Today GAE supports JAX-RS and JAXB so yes, you can use "cool" again!

Comment: I agree but the support of JAXB seems to be limited: see http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1267 for details.

Comment: SOAP now officially supported: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/soap.html. That's a great news!