# Metro web services on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-metro-framework

Has anyone tried to implement Metro web services on GAE-Java. It is not lsited on http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine and I would like to know if GAE will support it

Comment: Why not try it out and ask for specific answers if/when you encounter problems? I don't know if it's supported, but it's worth trying at least right?

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216571/creating-java-web-service-using-google-appengine), which outlines one approach. But really, Metro is quite a big framework/stack. What particular aspect of Metro do you want?

There is an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1270) for it, go and vote for it!